# Grouping by Date without Time component

Tags: sql, plsql, count

So i have a table that looks like this:

[image: table example]

As you can see some of the dates are the same however the time of day is different.

i have the following select statement (i have deleted and altered some data since this is rather sensitive):

```
  SELECT   LAST_UPD AS PERIOD,
         COUNT(CASE WHEN SOLVED_SECONDS /60 /60 <= 2 THEN 1 END) as completed_within_2hours, 
         COUNT(CASE WHEN STATUS ='Færdig' THEN +1 END) as completed_callbacks,
         COUNT(CASE WHEN SOLVED_SECONDS /60 /60 <= 2 THEN 1 END) / COUNT(CASE WHEN STATUS ='Færdig' THEN 1 END) * 100 as Percentage
FROM     TABLE
WHERE    LAST_UPD BETWEEN '2013-07-01' AND '2013-07-03'
AND      STATUS ='Færdig'
AND      AGENTGROUP IN ('Hovednumre','Forsikring','Hotline','Kunder')
GROUP BY LAST_UPD
```

Now i want my query to count when the DATES are the same so forexample if the date is 2013-07-01 i want it to count x amount for that day regardless of time of day.

I have tried the following:

```
SELECT  DISTINCT TO_CHAR(LAST_UPD, 'YYYY/MM/DD') AS PERIOD,
```

Sadly this returns each of days but doesnt count them correctly (it returns 1 for each day).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps what you want is to select and group by "Trunc(last_upd)"